# Fortran: Using Arrays in a Python way: derived types, Iteration over derived type

Tags: python, fortran

I am currently trying to get to know Fortran in more detail. In the process, i am trying to implement an algorithm, which i already implemented using python.
I have a small array, that looks something like this:

```
small_array = some_class(a, b, [x,y,z])
```

With s small arrays, a medium one is created.

```
medium_array = [small_array_1, small_array_2, ...]
```

With m medium arrays, a big array is created.

```
big_array = [medium_array_1, medium_array_2, ...]
```

I played around with derived-types in fortran, but this way I will only get the needed functionality in a way more difficult way.

What I would like to do is get the number of medium_array in the big_array and the number of small_arrays in the medium_array. I tried using `Extent(...)` but this won't work with derived types.
I would also like to access those derive type (or however this can be done) in an standard array way like e.g. `big_array(1,1,:)` in order to access all small_arrays of the first big_array and middle_array.

Is there anything to do this in a better way?

**EDIT**:
Here is what I am trying to define in Fortran (Python code):

```
H1_pg1a = primitive_gaussian(some values..) # These will be derive types in Fortran i suppose, in python these are implemented as class
H1_pg1b = primitive_gaussian(some values..)
H1_pg2a = primitive_gaussian(some values..)

H2_pg1a = primitive_gaussian(some values..)
H2_pg1b = primitive_gaussian(some values..)
H2_pg2a = primitive_gaussian(some values..)

H1_1s = [H1_pg1a, H1_pg1b] # These will be lists of derive types
H1_2s = [H1_pg2a]
H2_1s = [H2_pg1a, H2_pg1b]
H2_2s = [H2_pg2a]

molecule = [H1_1s, H1_2s, H2_1s, H2_2s] # These will be lists of lists of derive types
```

What I than need to do is get some info about the molecule:

```
nbasis = len(molecule)
```

and this will be implemented something like this:

```
   for i in range(nbasis):  # iteration über spalten
    for j in range(nbasis):  # iteraion über zeilen

        nprimitives_i = len(molecule[i])
        nprimitives_j = len(molecule[j])

        for k in range(nprimitives_i):
            for l in range(nprimitives_j):
...
```

I would like to then access the values of the class or derived types something like this

```
molecule[i][k].some_value
```

I started to implement `primitive_gaussian` as a derive type, and then define another derive type for the lists of derive type and for the lists of list of derive type. By doing this, i can only access the values with `molecule%H1_1s&H1_pg1a%some_value`, which I cannot iterate over.

Comment: I'm not at all sure I follow what you are asking - some code might really help. Are `small_array` and `medium_array` derived types? If so does the `Size` intrinsic do what you want?

Comment: I just added what i am trying to do in my question above, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Fortran and Python have very different ways of handling arrays-of-arrays.

The python snippet

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [a, b]
```

will result in a structure like

```py
c = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

But the superficially similar Fortran snippet

```
integer, allocatable :: a(:)
integer, allocatable :: b(:)
integer, allocatable :: c(:)

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [a, b]
```

will instead result in a structure like

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

i.e. the result of `[a, b]` in Fortran is a flattened array containing the contents of `a` and `b`, where the result of `[a, b]` in Python is an array containing `a` and `b` as separate objects.

If you want an array-of-arrays in Fortran, you will either have to use a multi-dimensional array, or to explicitly define wrapper types for each sub-array type.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is it also possible to allocate c and another c to another array if a and b are (different) derived types?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your comment. Could you give an example (ideally as a new stack overflow question)?